# Where should I store access token from LoopBack on the client side for future access?

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I'm trying to build a sample login view using AngularJS for the client side and LoopBack for server side.

When the user logs in, access token is created and returned in the response body. I want to use it for the next request to API server. Any idea of where to store the access token?

Comment: You could use localStorage

Comment: I chose localStorage. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the next access is always in the same session, I'd store it as a instance variable in an angular service.

If you need the token to persist across sessions then local storage or a cookie.

Comment: I found that Angular SDK provided by LoopBack store tokens to LocalStorage. So I chose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For server-side, persist the token to a local storage:

> ./server/model-config.json

```
"AccessToken": {
"dataSource": "local",
"public": false
},
```

See [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+component) on how to configure the storage.

Then, for the session to be also persisted client-side, I would recommend [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

> ./server/server.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({ 
     secret: 'keyboard cat', 
     resave: false, 
     saveUninitialized: false, 
     cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } // in milliseconds, cookie will expire after one minute
     }));
```

Answer (score 1):

In a client-server (HTML5 client + REST API) architecture tokens are often stored in sessionStorage:

```
// Store token
sessionStorage['token'] = token;

// Retrieve token
let token = sessionStorage['token'];
```

For tokens sessionStorage (which is cleared when the tab is closed) is probably the best. LocalStorage can also be used but the token will persist after the browser has closed. Cookies are the last resort.

However, if your client is a [Single Page Application (SPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) then you might consider simply keeping the token in a global variable.